# How to restrict Media Folder using Django ? Is it a way?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-views

I tried several tutorials using "FileResponse" to restrict the access to the MediaFolder only on authenticated User... But it does'nt run well online.

It ran on localhost, but definitly not online.

Is it a way or an App which can restrict the Media folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can achieve this goal by using `x-accel-redirect`, if you use nginx for serving (static and media files) or `X-Sendfile` if you are using apache.**

Technicaly, you get the file request on django, you check if the user should have an access to the file and then you send back a header with the filename inside to your instance of NGinx. Nginx then serve the file.

This snippet must help you if you are using `nginx` : [nginx x-accel-redirect protection of static files](https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/491/)